# ionic prod build throws Injector Error on run

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, runtime-error, ionic4

Building an ionic4 angular app with 'ionic cordova build android --prod'. Runs into Static injection error on device. Debug build with 'ionic serve', 'ionic cordova build android' and 'ionic cordova run android --device' do no throw this error.

Uses lazy load with app-routing.module and provided root level @ionic-natives in app.module. Since the error is cryptic with uglify, can't make out which service/module is the cause. Is there a way to disable uglify and minify to debug the issue

ionic info =>

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.3

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.1, (and 14 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/aniraj/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Linux 4.15
```

---

app.module.ts =>

```
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { RatingModule } from 'ngx-rating';
import { MomentModule } from 'ngx-moment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore'
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { SharedComponentModule } from './components/shared-components.module';
import { SharedModalModule } from './modals/shared-modals.module';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Chooser } from '@ionic-native/chooser/ngx';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer/ngx';
import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id/ngx';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
      entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MomentModule,
    RatingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,    
    AngularFireStorageModule, AngularFireFunctionsModule,
    SharedComponentModule, SharedModalModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }) 
  ],
  providers[
  StatusBar, Network, AppVersion, SplashScreen, EmailComposer, UniqueDeviceID, Chooser,
  { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Error on inspect on Chrome =>

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(a)[k -> r]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[k -> r]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for r!
    at pa.get (main.73d45aba5e0db24763c3.js:1)
    at main.73d45aba5e0db24763c3.js:1
    at e (main.73d45aba5e0db24763c3.js:1)
    at Ta.get (main.73d45aba5e0db24763c3.js:1)
    at main.73d45aba5e0db24763c3.js:1
    at e (main.73d45aba5e0db24763c3.js:1)
    at Ta.get (main.73d45aba5e0db24763c3.js:1)
    at _g (main.73d45aba5e0db24763c3.js:1)
    at Bg.get (main.73d45aba5e0db24763c3.js:1)
    at uy (main.73d45aba5e0db24763c3.js:1)
cordova.935a9f4e1f7afeca168d.js:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling aot should be enough to detect the injection error, no need for a full prod build.

Try something like:

```
ionic serve -- --aot
```